# Remove, release, or cancel which sounds most natural when used with the word "state"?

Tags: verbs

> This button is used to **remove/release/cancel** the locked state of the door.

I would like to know which of **remove, release, and cancel** is suitable for the sentence above I created.

I think *"This button is used to unlock the door"* may be better, but I would like answers to my question.

Comment: Does the same button relock the door? _Toggle_ might be the best option. Does the button have a label? _Cancel_ or _release_ are better than _remove_, but none of these options is optimal.

Answer (score 1):

> "This button is used to unlock the door"

Quite clear.

> This button is used to release the locked state of the door.

Pretty good.

> This button is used to remove the locked state of the door.

No. You don't "remove" a locked state.

> This button is used to cancel the locked state of the door.

No. It is not a computer popup.

Other random suggestions:

"The lock/unlock button"
"The unlock button"
"Press this button to unlock the door."
"Press this button to lock or unlock the door."

Comment: Plus oned. However I'd be tempted to put in bold, italic and caps the suggestion that they simply use the verb "unlock". The habituation to pursue the implementation of overly elaborated lexis in circumlocution regarding eventualities with synonymously perfect and demographically preferred words must be resisted.